# Swiper.js thumbs in Angular app synced prev & next

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, swiper.js

So I am using [Swiper.js](https://swiperjs.com/) for a multi-layered carousel on angular app. Essentially there was three `swiper-containers`, who's functionalities are supposed to complement each other. It is an extention of their [Swiper thumbs gallery](https://swiperjs.com/demos/#thumbs_gallery), where I added an extra crousel with description to the images.

Issues:

- When I click on a thumnail, the main image is no selected along with it. I need it to work like the image description. Simply put, when one clicks on a thumnails, the image description and the image preview should both change correspondingly.
- Oddly the Pagition count is wrong. It says 6, instead of the correct number 8.

Below is the component html:

```html
<section class="gallery-section">
  <div class="gallery-left">
    <div class="swiper-container gallery-text">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide" *ngFor="let image of imageArray; let i = index">
          <div class="image-controls">
            <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-mobile"></div>
            <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-mobile"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-mobile"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="image-info">
            <div class="image-description">{{ image.description }}</div>
            <div class="image-date">{{ image.date }}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-container gallery-thumbs">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide" *ngFor="let image of imageArray; let i = index">
          <figure>
            <img src="{{ image.img }}" alt="">
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-desktop"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-desktop"></div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-desktop"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-right">
    <div class="swiper-container gallery-main">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide" *ngFor="let image of imageArray">
          <figure>
            <img src="{{ image.img }}" alt="">
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Here is initialisation from the ts file:

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    imagesLoaded(document.querySelector('.gallery-section'), function(instance) {
      console.log('Images loaded > swiper start');
      var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
        spaceBetween: 5,
        slidesPerView: 3,
        freeMode: true,
        pagination: {
          el: '.swiper-pagination',
          type: 'fraction',
        },
        watchSlidesVisibility: true,
        watchSlidesProgress: true
      });
      var galleryText = new Swiper('.gallery-text', {
        slidesPerView: 1,
        thumbs: {
          swiper: galleryThumbs,
        },
        effect: 'fade',
        fadeEffect: {
          crossFade: true
        },
        navigation: {
          nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
          prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        }
      });
      var galleryMain = new Swiper('.gallery-main', {
        spaceBetween: 5,
        slidesPerView: 1,
        thumbs: {
          swiper: galleryThumbs
        },
        navigation: {
          nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
          prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Finally, a GIF which will hopefully make my issue easier to understand.
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    imagesLoaded(document.querySelector('.gallery-section'), function(instance) {
      console.log('Images loaded > swiper start');
      var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
        spaceBetween: 5,
        slidesPerView: 3,
        watchSlidesVisibility: true,
        watchSlidesProgress: true,
      });
      var galleryText = new Swiper('.gallery-text', {
        slidesPerView: 1,
        effect: 'fade',
        fadeEffect: {
          crossFade: true
        },
        navigation: {
          nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
          prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        }
      });
      var galleryMain = new Swiper('.gallery-main', {
        spaceBetween: 5,
        slidesPerView: 1,
        pagination: {
          el: '.swiper-pagination',
          type: 'fraction'
        },
        thumbs: {
          swiper: galleryThumbs
        }
      });
      galleryText.controller.control = galleryMain;
      galleryMain.controller.control = galleryText;
    });
  }
```